# How to sort by two meta keys in admin area?

Tags: query, admin-menu

I am sorting a custom post on a page by a meta key called `Order` ordered by `DESC` followed by a meta key called `Sub order` ordered by `ASC` but I can't fathom how to do the same sorting in the WordPress Admin area and I can't find any examples that combine the `$query->set('property', 'value')` syntax with an array assuming that's the correct method.

The working page custom query is:

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'resumeposts',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'resume_order' => array(
                'key' => 'Order',
                'type' => 'Numeric'
        ),
        'resume_suborder' => array(
                'key' => 'Sub order',
                'type' => 'Numeric'
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
            'resume_order' => 'DESC',
            'resume_suborder' => 'ASC'
    ),
    'nopaging' => true // Disable post limit per page
);
```

My existing sort order in the admin to which I'd like to add the Sub order sorting is:

```
function set_post_order_in_admin( $query ) {
  if ( is_admin() ) {

    if ( get_current_post_type() == "resumeposts" ) {
      $query->set( 'meta_key', 'Order' );
      $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
      $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'set_post_order_in_admin');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't find any examples that combine the `$query->set('property', 'value')` syntax with an array assuming that's the correct method

In your `$args` array, you defined both `meta_query` and `orderby` as arrays, and they are each an arg for `WP_Query` (or a value for the "property" above), hence in your custom function (`set_post_order_in_admin()`), just use `$query->set( 'meta_query', <array> )` and `$query->set( 'orderby', <array> )` like so:

```php
// In the set_post_order_in_admin function:

// Replace these lines:
$query->set( 'meta_key', 'Order' );
$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
$query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );

// with the following:

$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    'relation'        => 'AND',
    'resume_order'    => array(
        'key'  => 'Order',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
    'resume_suborder' => array(
        'key'  => 'Sub order',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
) );

$query->set( 'orderby', array(
    // <orderby>      => <order>
    'resume_order'    => 'DESC',
    'resume_suborder' => 'ASC'
) );
```

Or did you mean something else?

Also, you should run your filter only if the current `WP_Query` is the main WordPress query to avoid your custom filter from messing with other `WP_Query` calls. So you would do `if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() )` instead of just `if ( is_admin() )`.

Comment: No, that is exactly what I meant thank you, I'm so grateful for your help, it works perfectly. I struggled with it for a couple of days but couldn't find any examples referring to `$query->set( 'meta_query', ...)` and ended up completely confused. Now it is working I will go away and read up on the areas you suggested.